# Can you be stumped if the ball hit the bat or the batter?

Tags: cricket

Can you be stumped if the ball hit accidentally the bat or the batter before being caught by the wicket keeper?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Law 39 "Stumped"](https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/stumped) says:

> 39.1.1 The striker is out Stumped [...] if a ball which is delivered is not called No ball and he/she is out of his/her ground [...] and he/she has not attempted a run when his/her wicket is fairly put down by the wicket-keeper without the intervention of another fielder.

Note nothing which stops the batter being out if the ball hit them or their body.